# intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I am learning the concept of `Intent`s and the application I am working on crashes when i try to go from one intent to another,the intent object is fired on `onClickListener()` of a button.

Below is the code:

`intentdemo.java`: first activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class intentdemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(intentdemo.this,Intentdemo2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

       });




    }
}
```

`Intentdemo2.java`: Activity 2

```
package com.test.intent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Intentdemo2 extends Activity {
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),intentdemo.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.test.intent"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".intentdemo"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Intentdemo2"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

main.xml: for first activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button 
    android:text="Button" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout.xml: for second activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>
    <TextView 
    android:text="@string/text" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 

    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate if someone can point me towards my mistake here, first Activity is displayed, When i click on button it gives me the message "the activity has stopped unexpectedly", how should I debug in case the error in activity is not intuitive.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second activity is loading its layout from main.xml (`setContentView(R.layout.main);`), but is trying find button with id `R.id.button2`. There's no such button in the main layout, so attempting to set the click listener is crashing on trying to access `null` object.

The fix is simple - change the line to `setContentView(R.layout.layout);`. (On a separate note - change the name of that file from `layout.xml` to something else)

Comment: This worked, Thanks Franci, and yes I will keep in mind to change the name of the file from layout.xml to something else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here but shouldn't

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

be

```
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
```

in IntentDemo2

Answer (score 0):

I think youu have just copy and pasted main activity in second...so please change    `setContentView(R.layout.main);` to appropriate layout.

your first activity,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class intentdemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(intentdemo.this,Intentdemo2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

       });




    }
}
```

your second activity,

```
package com.test.intent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Intentdemo2 extends Activity {
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

}
```